# Java parsing atom xml in entity object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, atom-feed

I am working on a Java client application which will use REST webservices of different servers to exchange resources between the servers. In most of the cases, resources are in the form of [atom](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287.txt) xml. But it might vary when more system will come in consideration.

However, what I need is a way so that I can access the XMLs as objects. For example, a atom might represent a **`person`** and my client application has a **`Person`** class corresponding to that xml. Now i need a way to convert the XML to that object.

**Complexities:**

1. The XMLs will contain lots of non atom standard nodes.
2. Resources can be nested. Like a `person` atom might contain `friends` in

   - atom:content: calling person.friend will return `friend` object.
   - atom:feed. calling person.friends will return array of friends.
3. Need both way conversion. Like

   - XML => Object(what i just described)
   - Object => XML. client app will populate the object to send to the system.

**My So far investigation:**

1. **Using DOM based xml libraries:** My classes can contain xpaths of each attribute and using any DOM based xml parser to fetch the values from XML and populate objects. Ive tried with XOM.
2. **Jaxb:** I applied the marshaling and unmarshaling for simple XMLs but not sure about the robustness.
3. **Apache Abdera:** Came accross recently by my friend. Seems it supports the standard atom atttributes by default. But for non atom tags, how much extra work need to be done?

**Question:**

1. What is the preferred way to achieve the above?
2. Any guideline would be much more appreciable.

Comment: why do you think jaxb isn't robust?  it is a fairly significant library, and it underlies a variety of other libraries in java (e.g. jax-ws).

Comment: JAXB is ***very*** robust, and most implementations are very fast.

Comment: It may be best to start with a proof of concept.  If there is a specific use case you that is representative of the larger problem you are facing then you could add that to your question to get pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Thnx all for your replies. I will try to work with the JAXB with my scenarios. Will update my question with more details.